# Is there a powershell/graph api function for enabling "Microsoft Intune Connection" in security.microsoft.com

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a powershell/graph api function to enable this from https://security.microsoft.com.

It's in Settings->Endpoints->Advanced Features:

[Screenshot of UI settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu14A.png)

I've also looked in Developer Tools that there is no direct call to Microsoft Graph when saving the preferences.

Comment: As of now, there is no direct PowerShell cmdlet or Graph API endpoint that can be used to enable the "Microsoft Intune Connection" in https://security.microsoft.com. The management of the Intune Connection setting has to be done manually through the Microsoft 365 security center UI.